# Is there a way to hide all Chrome extension icons or make sure address bar is visible?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am often use few windows side by side and all extension icons are taking too much space. I hid the buttons for everything I rarely use, but then if I need it I have to go to extensions and enable buttons. This what it looks like and this is not the worst case even.

[image: This is what it looks like]

I have removed Home button, Apps button, but that is not enough. Is there something like OS X Bartender app that hides icons from menu bar or maybe another extension that can take control of the icons?

Comment: Related: In 108.0.5359.125 It's not possible to remove the _Share this page_ button anymore. Ungoogled Chromium [addresses it](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium/issues/1853). In Chrome Enterprise there is [DesktopSharingHubEnabled](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DesktopSharingHubEnabled), that item, or similar is not present in `chrome://flags` for a regular user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try dragging the omnibox's right edge in the right direction. It would hide some of the buttons you would be able to access later in a drop-down list which would appear on the right.

[image]

Comment: Damn it. I wish I knew that earlier. I am using chrome for years and it never occurred to me.

Comment: You can also choose individually the icons to hide, by right clicking them and choosing `Hide in Chrome Menu` [How to Rearrange or Hide the Extension Buttons on the Chrome Toolbar](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37911/google-chrome-adds-two-ways-to-hide-extension-icons/)

Comment: You saved me so much time! I didn't even know you can resize it! Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on latest Chrome 83.0.4103.116. The ability to drag that line disappeared. Now you have to click Jigsaw icon and pin/unpin the icons you want to see next to the URL bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [one click extension manager](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwic2riX5c_GAhUTc44KHdA0BIk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fone-click-extension-manag%2Fpbgjpgbpljobkekbhnnmlikbbfhbhmem&ei=p1KfVdzqBZPmuQTQ6ZDICA&usg=AFQjCNF2ihp35ApQ0_1QAuU5WdyrcJVRhA&bvm=bv.97653015,d.c2E) where you can do it with ease :

[image]

It will list all extensions and you could manage all extensions at a time

Comment: Installing! But who could've thought that you can drag the Url field wider.

Comment: @firedev this small piece of information really made my day, until now I was clicking "hide icon" for each of individual extension...